# De-Highlighting selected row on leaving selected row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, highlight

How to highlight selected row alone in `DataGridView`?

I tried `cell_click` event using for each loop in follwing code highlighting selected row works,
 but as on leaving that row should return to its original color.

```
     datagridviewrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

on `Form_Load` event:

```
datagridviewrow.MultiSelect = False
datagridviewrow.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect
datagridviewrow.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Tomato
```